# Cannot convert and save UTF-8 string to ANSI in java

Tags: java, utf-8, ansi

Here is my code. I have to write string to console in UTF-8 but save the string in ANSI. When I open file it's in UTF-8. What do I do?

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
bufferedReader.close();
String utfString = new String(message.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
String ansiMessage = new String(utfString.getBytes(), "WINDOWS-1251");
writeToFile(ansiMessage, "ANSI.txt", "WINDOWS-1251");
```

```
private static void writeToFile(String string, String path, String enc) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(path), enc));
    writer.write(string);
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: What's with the `utfString` and the `ansiMessage`? Do you think they do something useful? You can just write `message` to the file, with the correct encoding as you're doing. All that `getBytes()` is nonsense.

Comment: It's still in UTF-8

Comment: Based on what actual evidence?

Comment: i see it in standard txt app and also in notepad++

Comment: I think you may have a misunderstanding on how character encoding works. Especially how `UTF-8` uses a single byte to encode characters 0-127 and multiple bytes for ones beyond that. If you're only writing characters in the 0-127 range (such as the latin alphabets abcde), there's a lot of overlapping.

Comment: Here, read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `getBytes()` returns the bytes of the string in a default charset, which is usually UTF-16. Second, `new String(bytes[], string)` interpret the bytes as a string in the charset provided, it doesn't convert them. So:

`new String(message.getBytes(), "UTF-8")`

Try to read a UTF-16 string as UTF-8, bad. Then:

`new String(utfString.getBytes(), "WINDOWS-1251")`

Try to read the resulting string as WINDOWS-1251, equally bad.

I'm sure at this point your string is destroyed.

You can just call `getBytes(Charset)` to get the bytes of your string in the charset you want. But in your case you don't even need to do that, because your writeToFile(...) method already does charset conversion when writing to the file, so you can just give it the original `message`.

Comment: ```String output = new String(message.getBytes("WINDOWS-1251"));
                        writeToFile(output, "ANSI.txt", "WINDOWS-1251");``` Here is what I did and it's still UTF-8. I also gave original `message` but it also still in UTF-8

Comment: Well you are right. It was converted to ANSI actually however I will see UTF-8 mark in notepad

Comment: You wont see the encoding with notepad, you need an Hexadecimal editor to make sure of the encoding used.